# Crackling noise on passive speaker

Tags: speakers

I hope you are well.

I have bought 2 Skytronic 12" Speakers, 400W each, and they used to be working fine a while ago. One of them is an active speaker, and the other one a passive speaker. The active speaker is connected to the laptop using an rca to aux cable, and the passive speaker is basically connected to the active speaker using a red and black cable wire.
Recently, one of the speakers (the passive one) is making a very disturbing crackling noise and the sound is not clear at all. I have tried a different cable wire, but the problem is still the same.
I am really a newbie in fixing stuff, but I am willing to try almost anything to fix it! 
I would really appreciate your help.

Best regards, Kyri

Comment: It seems to be a physical defect. Try to check with a different input signal. If the crackling noise remain it is an hardware problem of the speakers. If the noise disappear it should be in the connector of the laptop. In this case you should listen noise even changing the speaker. Good Luck and welcome on SuperUser.

Comment: Hello and many thanks for your response!
What exactly do you mean by 'checking with a different input signal'? How can I do that? (Sorry for that question, i am actually a newbie at these stuff)

Comment: Problem finding: you have to find __where is__ the problem. Your system is made by 1. Something that produce the signal (sound) alias the laptop. 2. A Cable 3.Something that create the sound from the signal (the speakers).If you change the source of the signal (try with an HiFi, another laptop...) and the problem disappears it was the laptop. If you change the speakers (try an headset) with the same laptop and the problem remain it was there (the speakers). If you see the woofer and it is broken, well...the problem is there :-). Check the plug, if touching/rotating it does the crackling noise.